# Cinnamon Desktop - Clicking menu->shutdown presents no real button options?

Tags: shutdown, menu, cinnamon

When I click Menu then Shutdown (Quit) i get the following dialog:

```
______________________________
| Session                   x |
______________________________
|                             |
| Shutdown this system now?   |
| __________                  |
| |Cancel  x|                 |
-------------------------------
```

(Seems like I can't press print screen when the shutdown dialog is open so I can't provide a screenshot for this issue.)

Why have I only got a cancel button and how do I fix this as there used to be shutdown, reboot, logout?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found this somewhere else and it fixed the problem for me.

> Updating to Cinnamon 2.6 (using the PPA ppa:moorkai/cinnamon), and
>   executing the commands below, has solved the issue for me (after a
>   restart).
>
> ```
> gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session settings-daemon-uses-logind true
> gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session session-manager-uses-logind true
> gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session screensaver-uses-logind false
> ```

Comment: Had this same issue, while running cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04. This did the trick (reboot required, though)

Comment: I did it with `dconf-editor` but used the same keys. Logging out and in again was required, reboot would do the trick as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install consolekit
```

and reboot.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found this and worked for me: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1533771#p1533771

> I was able to fix that using dconf-editor under **org.cinnamon.desktop.session** set **session-manager-uses-logind** to *true* then logout and back in again and shutdown button should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually figured out that if you install dconf-editor then open it and browse to apps->indicator-session, there are some check boxes there, I ticked them all to get the buttons back. Weird because they are all labelled as suppress, ticking them enabled the buttons?

Anyways... It works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I,ve fixed the bug on Ubuntu 14.04. I am running Cinnamon 2.8
and using dconf under org.cinnamon.desktop.session set session-manager-uses-logind to true should resolve the problem.

Write this on yor terminal:

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.session session-manager-uses-logind true
```